# How to fetch value of vDateField on change by using Django Admin Datepicker widget?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to fetch the value of a date field in Django admin using jquery.

Right now I have managed to fetch the value of the text field if its manually changed, but if the value is changed using admin date picker widget, the code isn't working.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $('#id_start_date_0').bind('change', function() {
      alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a user manually inputs a date, and then moves focus away from the date input (e.g. by pressing Tab), the `change` event fires. But this event does *not* fire when the user changes the date with the default date picker. Luckily, the date picker javascript does [focus on the date field](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c8250ef361dcb4c7ed76632e4308c6db22da77d0/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js#L408) after a date is entered. This javascript should cover both cases:

```
$('#id_start_date_0').on('change focus', function() {
      alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: No one answered this. Thanks a lot. Working fine for Django 2.2!!

Answer (score 0):

I did this by getting the id of the calendar using inspect element.

```
$('#calendarbox0').click(function() {
         alert($(this).val());
});
$('#id_start_date_0').on('change', function() {
      alert($(this).val());
});
```